# How to install phpMyAdmin with PHP 7.2

Tags: 20.04, php, phpmyadmin

I have installed PHP 7.2 from `ppl:ondrej/php` along with most of the required modules.  I want to install phpMyAdmin but for some reason it wants to install modules from PHP 7.1 and 8.0.  What's the cleanest way to install this without unnecessary modules of a wrong version?  I could not find a phpMyAdmin in the ondrej repo, so this is version 4.4.9 from focal repo.

```
# apt install phpmyadmin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dbconfig-common dbconfig-mysql icc-profiles-free javascript-common libjs-jquery libjs-openlayers libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore libmcrypt4
  php-google-recaptcha php-mysql php-phpmyadmin-motranslator php-phpmyadmin-shapefile php-phpmyadmin-sql-parser php-phpseclib php-psr-cache
  php-psr-container php-psr-log php-symfony-cache php-symfony-cache-contracts php-symfony-expression-language php-symfony-service-contracts
  php-symfony-var-exporter php-tcpdf php-twig php-twig-extensions php7.1-common php7.1-mcrypt php8.0-common php8.0-mysql
Suggested packages:
  libmcrypt-dev mcrypt php-dbase php-libsodium php-gmp php-symfony-service-implementation php-imagick php-twig-doc php-symfony-translation www-browser
  php-recode php-gd2 php-pragmarx-google2fa php-bacon-qr-code php-samyoul-u2f-php-server
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dbconfig-common dbconfig-mysql icc-profiles-free javascript-common libjs-jquery libjs-openlayers libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore libmcrypt4
  php-google-recaptcha php-mysql php-phpmyadmin-motranslator php-phpmyadmin-shapefile php-phpmyadmin-sql-parser php-phpseclib php-psr-cache
  php-psr-container php-psr-log php-symfony-cache php-symfony-cache-contracts php-symfony-expression-language php-symfony-service-contracts
  php-symfony-var-exporter php-tcpdf php-twig php-twig-extensions php7.1-common php7.1-mcrypt php8.0-common php8.0-mysql phpmyadmin
0 upgraded, 31 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 17.3 MB of archives.
```

Here is what I have installed

```
# apt list --installed | grep php

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libapache2-mod-php7.2/focal,now 7.2.34-10+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php-common/focal,now 2:80~exp2+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 all [installed,automatic]
php7.2-bz2/focal,now 7.2.34-10+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed]
php7.2-cli/focal,now 7.2.34-10+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php7.2-common/focal,now 7.2.34-10+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php7.2-curl/focal,now 7.2.34-10+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed]
php7.2-gd/focal,now 7.2.34-10+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed]
php7.2-json/focal,now 7.2.34-10+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php7.2-mbstring/focal,now 7.2.34-10+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed]
php7.2-mysql/focal,now 7.2.34-10+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed]
php7.2-opcache/focal,now 7.2.34-10+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php7.2-readline/focal,now 7.2.34-10+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php7.2-xml/focal,now 7.2.34-10+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed]
php7.2-zip/focal,now 7.2.34-10+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed]
php7.2/focal,now 7.2.34-10+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 all [installed]
```

Answer (score 1):

As phpMyAdmin is just a PHP web application, you can download the original phpMyAdmin ZIP file from https://www.phpmyadmin.net/, unpack it to some subdirectory within your web server directory and manually configure it according to the documentation on the site.

Comment: Good point, but I was hoping for an apt repo approach so I can get automatic updates.

Answer (score 0):

Even though PHP 7.2 is installed, it is probably not the default version. You can check the default [cli](https://www.abbreviations.com/term/36876) version with `php --version` and the web served version with the PHP function `phpinfo()`.

To change the default cli PHP version use

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

To change the web served version, you need to change the web server configuration, i.e. the Apache virtual host file.

Only then, when installing phpMyAdmin you'll get the modules for the right PHP version.

If you want to setup a local web development environment, allow me to suggest using [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/) - it allows you to use any PHP (or any other software) version and you can use multiple versions at the same time and it keeps your local system clean. There are many tutorials on internet. [This one](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-a-docker-based-lamp-stack-using-docker-on-ubuntu-20-04) should get you nicely started.

Comment: PHP 7.2 is the only version I have installed.  It shows in both command-line `php --version` and `phpinfo()`